# How to make a JavaScript animation responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, responsive

I am trying to make this java script animation responsive: https://codepen.io/lateek35/pen/QbZdEB. This is my website http://gerydi.com/sincera/.

and I used this, but it only fits the box size, not the whole text. Do you have any ideas how can I fix it? Font size doesn't affect my text.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #canvas{
        width: 360px!important;
        font-size: 7px!important;
        margin-top:50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information/code, i cannot understand what is it about.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the codepen example you provided, you can change the text size in the `writeText` function:

```
var textSample = new PIXI.Text(text, { font: '50px Calibri, sans-serif', fill: 'black', align: 'left' });
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXVzxm). Do you have access to that function? If not, you'll have to figure out a way to pass in the font settings.